# Getting weird errors from mongodb - certain options that I didn't elect are not supported?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using:

```
import * as mdb from 'mongodb'
```

and when I initialize a mongodb connection:

```
const d = new mdb.MongoClient(url, {
   useNewUriParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true
});
```

and then connect with:

```
const conn = d.connect();
```

I eventually get this raw message in the console:

> ```
> the options [servers] is not supported
> the options [caseTranslate] is not supported
> the options [dbName] is not supported
> ```

anyone know why I get that? And why the messages aren't prefaced saying where they are coming from etc?

And then I get this internal error:

```
Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at _initializeCursor (/Users/Olegzandr/codes/interos/read-from-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js:307:40)
    at handleCallback (/Users/Olegzandr/codes/interos/read-from-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:32:5)
    at nextFunction (/Users/Olegzandr/codes/interos/read-from-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:879:5)
    at /Users/Olegzandr/codes/interos/read-from-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:829:7
    at _getMore (/Users/Olegzandr/codes/interos/read-from-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js:349:7)
    at wireProtocol.getMore (/Users/Olegzandr/codes/interos/read-from-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:301:7)
    at queryCallback (/Users/Olegzandr/codes/interos/read-from-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/wireprotocol/get_more.js:54:5)
    at /Users/Olegzandr/codes/interos/read-from-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:420:18
    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:70:11)
```

Comment: so..how can I report this error to the mongodb folks?

Comment: What's your node driver version and your MongoDB server version?

Comment: 3.3.2 is the version

Comment: supposedly the node.js driver version and mongodb versions arent in sync which is quite dumb. since I am using mongod v4.0

Comment: it looks like 4.2 is the latest mongod version and 3.3.2 is latest mongodb nodejs driver version, so Im using the latest basically

Comment: Are you using change Streams and a replica set? I am getting the same error after reconnecting to the DB  after an network error. Then it seems that the change stream is not properly reconnecting as well and thus throwing that error